# Display data in a loop but instead of looping it all there will be break in each data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to display a series of questions depends on the length of my array.

instead of displaying it all, I want to display my questions and choices one by one.

my array is like this:

choices_array

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 25
        [question_id] => 7
        [choice] => gas shortage
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 26
        [question_id] => 7
        [choice] => panic buying
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 27
        [question_id] => 7
        [choice] => Hurricane Harvey
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 28
        [question_id] => 7
        [choice] => help from oil companies
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 29
        [question_id] => 8
        [choice] => for people to purchase normally
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 30
        [question_id] => 8
        [choice] => for markets to increase their prices
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 31
        [question_id] => 8
        [choice] => for people to stock up while they can
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 32
        [question_id] => 8
        [choice] => for drivers to rush to refill their tanks
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 33
        [question_id] => 9
        [choice] => to make everyone panic over gas shortages
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 34
        [question_id] => 9
        [choice] => to publish how Texans reacted to fuel scarcity
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 35
        [question_id] => 9
        [choice] => to announce the effects of Hurricane Harvey in Texas
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 36
        [question_id] => 9
        [choice] => to inform the public of the closing of several oil refineries
        )
    )
```

question_array

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 7
    [question] => How do the travel abroad courses help students?
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 8
    [question] => Who can participate in the travel abroad program?
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 9
    [question] => Which statement would the author likely agree with?
    )
```

I want to have a output like this

```
1.What was the Murrays’ overall impression of Randy’s service?
   A. gas shortage
   B. panic buying
   C  hurricane harvey
   D  help from oil companies

     Submit -> this will be button
```

then after they click submit, it will go to another question which is on the array.

here is the code that I have currently.

```
function display() {
  $.ajax({
      url: url +,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.choices.length; i++) {

            if (data.choices.length < 0) {
              
            }else{
              $('#display_question').text(data.choices[i].question);
              data.choices.splice(i, 1);
              break;
            }

        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Error adding / update data');
      }
  });
}
```

My controller

```
   public function get_question_choices($scenario_id){

    $choices_array = [];
    $newQuesArr = [];

    $questions = Question::select(
      'question.id',
      'question.component AS question',
    )
    ->from('questions AS question')
    ->leftJoin('scenarios AS scenario', 'scenario.id', '=', 'question.scenario_id')
    ->where('question.scenario_id',$scenario_id)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    foreach ($questions as $key => $value) {

      $choices = Question::select(
        'choice.id',
        'choice.question_id',
        'choice.choice'
      )
      ->from('question_choices AS choice')
      ->leftJoin('questions AS question', 'question.id', '=', 'choice.question_id')
      ->where('question.scenario_id',$scenario_id)
      ->where('choice.question_id',$value['id'])
      ->get()
      ->toArray();


      array_push($choices_array, $choices);

      $newQuesArr[$key] = ['question' => $value['question']];

      foreach($choices_array[$key] as $choice) {
          $newQuesArr[$key]['choices'] = $choice['choice'];
      }

    }

    return response()->json([
      'questions' => $choices_array,
      'choices' => $newQuesArr,
      'success'=>'Success'
   ]);
  }
```

```
[0] => Array (
    [question] => What is the main purpose of this letter?
    [choices] => help from oil companies
    )
[) Array ( 0] => Array (
    [question] => What is the main purpose of this letter?
    [choices] => help from oil companies
    )
[1] => Array (
    [question] => Why is it important to give the dogs potty breaks so frequently?
    [choices] => for drivers to rush to refill their tanks
    )
[2] => Array (
    [question] => Where will Socks, Lily, and Sandra stay over the weekend?
    [choices] => to inform the public of the closing of several oil refineries
    )
```

I can only display the question but I still don't know how can I get all of the choices from that question. can anyone help me, I really don't know what to do. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How about showing us the code in the PHP script file pointed to by `url`

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi sir, please check again. i already updated it.

Comment: So that array is returned by that PHP code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
$questions = [
0 => [
    'question' => "What was the Murrays overall impression of Randy's service?",
    'choice' => 'gas shortage',
    ],
1 => [
    'question' => "What was the Murrays overall impression of Randy's service?",
    'choice' => 'panic buying',
    ],
2 => [
    'question' => "What was the Murrays overall impression of Randy's service?",
    'choice' => 'Hurricane Harvey',
    ],
3 => [
    'question' => "What was the Murrays overall impression of Randy's service?",
    'choice' => 'Help from oil companies',
    ],
4 => [
    'question' => 'What did Randy do first?',
    'choice' => 'for people to purchase normally'
    ],
5 => [
    'question' => 'What did Randy do first?',
    'choice' => 'for markets to increase their prices'
    ],
6 => [
    'question' => 'What did Randy do first?',
    'choice' => 'for people to stock up while they can'
    ],
7 => [
    'question' => 'What did Randy do first?',
    'choice' => 'for drivers to rush to refill their tanks'
    ],
];

$prevQues = '';
$newQues = [];
foreach($questions as $question) {
    $quesText = $question['question'];
    $quesChoice = $question['choice'];
    if($prevQues !== $quesText) {
        $newQues[] = ['question' => $quesText, 'choice' => [$quesChoice]];
        $prevQues = $quesText;
    } else {
        $newQues[count($newQues)-1]['choice'][] = $quesChoice;
    }
}
```

Now, the **$newQues** will have correctly combined data. Each question one time with all its choices as an array.

******EDITED******

```
$newQuesArr = [];
foreach($question_array as $index => $question) {
    $newQuesArr[$index] = ['question' => $question['question']];
    foreach($choices_array[$index] as $choice) {
        $newQuesArr[$index]['choices'][] = $choice['choice']; // changed
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP realises this, the question is How Do I DO That???

Comment: yes that is the approach that i am trying to do, but I am really having a hardtime on manipulating my data on arrays.

Comment: Are you getting the array you posted from **get_question_choices** function?

Comment: yes sir @Tushar, i already edited my code in my Controller i already seperated the getting of question and choices, i just dont know on how can i make my array like that.

Comment: @Tushar hi sir i edited again my controller, i already loop the choices based on the length and question_id of the question table. i just need to combine both of it, but i have no idea on how can i do it,

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check. If you need any clarification regarding this, let me know:)

Comment: @Tushar hi sir, i am trying to do the right way so that i can learn the right way on how to do it, i am trying the first suggestion of yours, i already updated my array please check it again. i think i am almost near on the solution that you suggested, can you try to help me sir?

Comment: @shadow_blade, I have again updated my answer, please check:)

Comment: @Tushar hi sir, here is the array result that i am receiving from the response please see the updated array. it is just displaying one choices from each question.

Comment: Change this line in my answer above, from ```$newQuesArr[$index]['choices'] = $choice['choice'];``` to ```$newQuesArr[$index]['choices'][] = $choice['choice'];``` Now, it should display all the choices from each question.

Comment: @Tushar thank you so much for the help sir, i really learned today. can i ask one more question sir? how can i add in the choice their id? which is the choice['id']

Comment: Glad to know, I could help you and that you learned something new today:)